# mySQL search function returning invalid results

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

When running a SQL command to search a small database (using for testing as I'm learning) it gives me very strange results. Can you see what's wrong with my command?

```
SELECT * FROM users,departments WHERE name LIKE '%Alex%' OR lastname LIKE '%Alex%' OR email LIKE '%Alex%' AND departments.departmentid = users.departmentid
```

As you can see below it shows the users it searches for in all departments, when each user is only registered to one.

Search Query and results 
[image: Search Query]
Users Table
[image: Users Table]
Departments table
[image: Departments Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users,departments WHERE (name LIKE '%Alex%' OR lastname LIKE '%Alex%' OR email LIKE '%Alex%') AND departments.departmentid = users.departmentid
```

You have to make brackets arround the `or` statements.

Answer (score 1):

First, use explicit `join` conditions with an `on` clause.  If you are learning SQL, you should learn it right.

```
SELECT *
FROM users JOIN
     departments
     ON departments.departmentid = users.departmentid
WHERE name LIKE '%Alex%' OR lastname LIKE '%Alex%' OR email LIKE '%Alex%';
```

That will fix your problem, which also could have been fixed by using parentheses to group the comparisons.  But, fixing the `join` is the right thing to do.

Comment: @AlexBunt . . . If you used a comma in the `from` clause, then you have learned `join`s.  And you should learn how to express them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why you can try an `inner join` here

```
SELECT * FROM `user` as usr
   INNER JOIN `department` as dprt on usr.departmentid =dprt.departmentid
WHERE usr.name LIKE '%Alex%' OR usr.lastname LIKE '%Alex%' OR usr.email LIKE '%Alex%'
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to use parentheses in your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users, departments
WHERE (name LIKE '%Alex%' OR lastname LIKE '%Alex%' OR email LIKE '%Alex%')
       AND departments.departmentid = users.departmentid;
```